# Adjoint map and $V \cong V^{**}$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, bilinear-form

I am confused after following these lines

> Note that the adjoint of a bilinear form $B:V\rightarrow V^{*}$ would have the same type $B^{*}:V\rightarrow V^{*}$ (adjoint map) (using $V^{**} \cong V$ ). Only for bilinear forms, we can compare $B$ with $B^{*}$ as they are objects of the same type.

1. What does the word "Type" mean in this context?
2. $V^{**} \cong V$, obviously, this equality is **up to isomorphism**. Why are we allowed to replace $V^{**}$ as the domain of $B^{*}$ with $V$? Since the objects in $V$ are vectors and objects in $V^{**}$ are maps that take in covectors and spit out scalars. Why is replacing the domain with another set containing elements of different nature does not affect $B^{*}$! Isomorphism preserves the algebraic structure but here we are replacing the objects we take as input with totally different objects. How is this not affecting the map? I cannot come up with an example in this context that clearly shows that this replacement is unimportant.

---

The responses made by the community has not yet provided a satisfactory answer to my question.

Comment: Only the algebraic structure matters (also the isomorphism is canonical for finite-dimensional spaces). How about this: is there any sense in which the numerals $1,2,3$ convey more/better meaning than I,II,III? Likewise, is there any reason to think that (modulo human translation inaccuracies) a book in English has any less/more meaning than a book in French?

Comment: “Type” means they’re both maps $V\to V^*$.

Comment: I cannot understand how the analogy that isomorphism is just renaming the elements is actually working here. $B^{*}$ is taking linear maps from $V^{*}$ as input but after the replacement the inputs are vectors. How is that not changing the nature of the map? It is just unintuitive **why in this case this replacement is not important**

Comment: So this means you don’t really understand the nature of the isomorphism $V\cong V^{**}$, so that’s where you should start. We very frequently make such replacements, for example in a simpler situation, $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}\cong\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^m$ (almost every definition of $\Bbb{R}^p$ I can think of makes these two different sets with only an isomorphism linking them). Once you accept that $V\cong V^{**}$ is a “good and natural” (though certainly not initially intuitive) isomorphism, you’ll have no problem making the replacements.

Comment: Anyway, if you really don’t like this, then just let $\iota:V\to V^{**}$ be the canonical isomorphism (assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional of course (or in functional analysis, considering topological duals and assuming reflexivity)), and consider $\tilde{B}:=B^*\circ\iota:V\to V^*$; it is this map they are actually calling the adjoint. After a bunch of calculations/proving theorems you’ll quickly get tired of writing the $\iota$ everywhere and realize that it served no other real purpose than to satisfy an initial uneasiness. So you’ll  end up saying things like $\tilde{B}=B^*$ (or $\cong$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, I am looking for an explanation in the context of my question. Making analogies with other fields just makes things more confusing. By replacing the $V^{**}$ with $V$, we are indeed making $B$ and $B^{*}$ the same type. But before replacement, they were not of the same type! However, I still do not understand why such replacement is allowed.

Comment: Fine, we have three maps in the game: a linear map $B:V\to V^*$, its dual/transpose map $B^t:V^{**}\to V^*$ (I actually don't like to call this the adjoint, because in my mind I reserve that term for when we're dealing with an (pseudo) inner-product space) and we have the map $\tilde{B}:=B\circ\iota:V\to V^*$. All the information that is present in $B^t$ is exactly the information contained in $\tilde{B}$, because $\iota$ is an isomorphism. I can literally go back and forth. Every statement I make regarding $B^t$, I can make an analogous statement about $\tilde{B}$, and vice-versa.

Comment: Furthermore, the isomorphism $\iota$ is natural (in the sense that no bases or extra information was used, i.e it's the next best thing to equality). Also, we're talking linear algebra, so we only care about the linear structure. If you can't claim one or the other is better, then from the perspective of linear algebra, there's nothing which forces us to consider one over the other. Besides this, I'm not sure what else I can say to convince you that first of all, *we can* do this, and secondly, there is no harm in doing this (besides an initial knee-jerk reaction).

Comment: Oh and I just realized: while we're trying to distinguish equality from isomorphism, I could raise the question of why you didn't object to calling $B:V\to V^*$ a bilinear form. Clearly, this is a linear map, not a bilinear form. Maybe it's because you know that every bilinear form on $V$ gives rise to a linear map $V\to V^*$ (actually in general, two of them, but if your bilinear form is symmetric, there is only one) and conversely.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You defined $\iota:V\to V^{**}$ and $B:V\to V^*$. Why is the composition $\tilde{B}$ from $V$ to $V^{*}$? Should not $B$ be from $V^{**}$ to $V^{*}$?

Comment: sorry $\tilde{B}:=B^t\circ \iota$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Why do you say "Every statement I make regarding $B^t$, I can make an analogous statement about $\tilde{B}$, and vice-versa"? In addition, "All the information that is present in $B^t$ is exactly the information contained in $\tilde{B}$", what do you mean by the word "information"? I wish you were more rigorous since I think I cannot follow the logical steps toward a conclusion. Here we know that $\iota$ is bijective, i.e. it has an inverse. Probably it is time to write an answer to the question instead of comments.

Answer (score 2):

---

1. The term "type" is being employed in a colloquial manner to denote the category of mathematical entity under consideration. The assertion that $B$ and $B^*$ are of the same type signifies that they both function as linear maps, mapping from a vector space $V$ to its dual space $V^*$..
2. The statement $V^{**} \cong V$ asserts the existence of a bijective mapping $I: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ that preserves the vector space structure. This implies that the linear transformation $I$ exhibits the properties of preserving addition and scalar multiplication, specifically, $I(v_1 + v_2) = I(v_1) + I(v_2)$ and $I(c v) = c I(v)$ vectors $\mathbf{\forall} v, v_1, v_2$ in the vector space $V$ and scalar $c$ in the field $\mathbb{R}$ (or any other field under consideration).

---

However, the elements of $V$ and $V^{**}$ are fundamentally different objects: $V$ is a set of vectors, while $V^{**}$ is a set of linear functionals on $V^*$. So, when we replace $V^{**}$ with $V$, what we're really doing is replacing each element $v^{**} \in V^{**}$ with its corresponding $v \in V$ under the isomorphism $I$.

It's crucial to note that the "replacement" does not change the nature of the objects. What changes is our perspective, or how we label the objects. The structure-preserving map $I$ allows us to identify each functional in $V^{**}$ with a vector in $V$ in a way that preserves the algebraic structure, and it is in this sense that we say $V^{**} \cong V$. So when we say $B^*$ is a map from $V$ to $V^*$ instead of from $V^{**}$ to $V^*$, what we really mean is that $B^*$ operates on the elements of $V$ that correspond under the isomorphism to the elements of $V^{**}$ that $B^*$ would normally operate on.

For example, consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. An isomorphism $I: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ might be defined by $I(v)(f) = f(v)$ for all $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$, where $V^*$ is the set of all linear maps $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Notice that $I(v)$ is indeed a linear map from $V^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so it belongs to $V^{**}$. However, by using the isomorphism $I$, we can "identify" each $v \in V$ with its corresponding $I(v) \in V^{**}$, and vice versa.

Comment: So if $B^{*}:V^{**}\rightarrow V^{*}$ and the isomorphism is $I: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ when we say we replace $V^{**}$ with $V$ we are actually defining the map as $B^{*}:I(V)\rightarrow V^{*}$? That is, when we write $B^{*}:V\rightarrow V^{*}$ we actually mean $B^{*}:I(V)\rightarrow V^{*}$?

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you asked

> Why do you say "Every statement I make regarding $B^t$, I can make an analogous statement about $\tilde{B}$, and vice-versa"?

Well, the reason I say that is because $\iota$ is an isomorphism. Ok maybe you’re tired of hearing that, but that really is the reason. You also asked what I meant by “information contained in the maps”, well as you’ll see in the examples below this can refer to literally any property of that function (e.g injectivity, surjectivity, bijectivity, rank, nullity, etc). Here are some examples

- $B^t$ and $\tilde{B}$ have the same image. Hence, they both have the same rank. Therefore, $B^t$ is surjective if and only if $\tilde{B}$ is.
- $\ker(B^t)=\iota[\ker \tilde{B}]$. Therefore, $B^t$ is injective if and only if $\tilde{B}$ is.
- putting the previous two statements together, we see that $B^t$ is bijective (hence a linear isomorphism) if and only if $\tilde{B}$ is.
- Fix a $\lambda\in V^*$ and consider the solutions to the equations $\tilde{B}(v)=\lambda$, and $B^t(\zeta)=\lambda$, i.e consider the sets $S_{\tilde{B},\lambda}=\{v\in V\,:\, \tilde{B}(v)=\lambda\}$, and let $S_{B^t,\lambda}=\{\zeta\in V^{**}\,:\, B^t(\zeta)=\lambda\}$. Then, you can immediately conclude that $\iota$ maps $S_{\tilde{B},\lambda}$ bijectively onto $S_{B^t,\lambda}$ (in fact these are affine subspaces, and $\iota$ is an affine bijective mapping between these spaces). In other words, if you know all the solutions to one equation, you know them for the other equation as well.

We can keep going. Ask me any question you like about $B^t$. I can then rephrase that into a question about $\tilde{B}$. Likewise, if you manage to answer one of these questions then by a simple rewording, you also know the answer to the other one. That’s the whole point of $\iota$ being an isomorphism.

So, yes you’re correct that $\tilde{B}$ and $B^t$ are different maps. But so what? They’re related by composition of an isomorphism, so they tell you the same thing (notice also that $\iota$ is not just some random bijection; it is linear which is what gives us for example the statement about kernels in the second bullet point). The stuff I said here goes through for any triple of vector spaces $X,Y,Z$ and linear maps $T:Y\to Z$ and $S:X\to Z$ and a linear isomorphism $\phi:X\to Y$ such that $S=T\circ \phi$. In the case we’re talking about, the reason why we even bother with introducing the $\iota$ is because it is a natural isomorphism; its existence does not rely on me specifying any extra information like a choice of basis. One could (but one doesn’t, without good reason) introduce an arbitrary isomorphism $\phi_1:V\to\Bbb{F}^n$, $\phi_2:V^*\to\Bbb{F}^n$ and $\phi_3:V^{**}\to\Bbb{F}^n$, and talk solely about the corresponding induced linear maps $\Bbb{F}^n\to\Bbb{F}^n$ (or what amounts to the same thing, certain matrix representations). But one doesn’t generally do this because the isomorphisms introduced here are unnatural.

Comment: According to your explanation, can we say that if $\iota:V\to V^{**}$ is the isomorphism when we replace $V^{**}$ with $V$ we are saying that by $B^{*}:V\rightarrow V^{*}$ we actually mean $B^{*}:\iota(V)\rightarrow V^{*}$? That is, we are replacing $V^{**}$ with $\iota(V)$ indeed.

Comment: umm $V^{**}=\iota[V]$, and this is an actual, no hidden-meaning, completely honest equal sign, because $\iota$ is an isomorphism, so in particular surjective. Also, I told you exactly what is meant in an earlier comment. $B^{t}:V^{**}\to V^*$ is the dual map, and what they’re calling the adjoint map of $B:V\to V^*$ is what I’m writing $\tilde{B}=B^t\circ\iota:V\to V^*$.

Comment: The fact that we are composing the isomorphism with $B$ without writing it is the main source of confusion. This isomorphic map to me seems an extra thing and a sign that the two objects under consideration are not actually replaceable. Yes, the structure, meaning the vector space addition and scalar multiplication are preserved but the actual value of the maps are not the same from the computational perspective and the isomorphic map should always go back and forth between two spaces. I don't know why mathematicians do not consider this and just preserving the structure seems enough for them.

Comment: yes, it is confusing when first learning, especially since it is so abstract, and yes when one is first teaching this stuff, they should not omit the various hidden isomorphisms; that’s just poor pedagogy. It took me about a year to fully digest it when I first learnt this stuff. But simpler examples eventually convinced me that it’s fine. Like I said already, $1,2,3…$ vs I,II,III… We have $1+1=2$ and $I+I=II$, and so on. Is one set of equations better than the other? You just have to spend some time thinking about it, and eventually you’ll be ok with it as well.

Comment: regarding “the value of the maps are not the same”, ok sure, but like in my fourth bullet point (which is really about computations/solving equations) the map $\iota$ literally tells you how to go back and forth, it provides a “mathematical dictionary”. This is why the only relevant thing is structure, not the concrete “implementation” of things.